# ORA-31600 when using scan_percent with dbms_comparison.compare

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm using **Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production** and I've created a comparison using this code :

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_COMPARISON.CREATE_COMPARISON(
    comparison_name => 'test2',
    schema_name     => 'someSchema',
    object_name     => 'someTable',
    dblink_name     => 'MYORACLEDB',
    scan_mode       => 'RANDOM',
    scan_percent    => 50);
END;
```

WHen i execute the comparison using

```
DECLARE
  consistent   BOOLEAN;
  scan_info    DBMS_COMPARISON.COMPARISON_TYPE;
BEGIN
consistent := DBMS_COMPARISON.COMPARE(
                  comparison_name => 'test2',
                  scan_info => scan_info,
                  perform_row_dif => FALSE);
END;
```

I get the following error message :

```
ORA-31600: invalid input value 1 for parameter data type in function a_plus_b_mul_c_minus_d
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_COMPARISON", line 547
ORA-06512: at line 7
31600. 00000 -  "invalid input value %s for parameter %s in function %s"
*Cause:    A NULL or invalid value was supplied for the parameter.
*Action:   Correct the input value and try the call again.
```

When i run a comparison with the full scan mode i've got no error.

Anybody encountered such issue ?

Comment: Try using the scan mode constants defined in DBMS_COMPARISON (in your case you should use `DBMS_COMPARISON.CMP_SCAN_MODE_RANDOM` instead of `'RANDOM'`) and see if that helps. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi Bob , thank you for this suggestion but unfortunatly I obtained the same behaviour with the package's constant.

Comment: There is bug number 19158337 getting same error with scan mode CYCLIC when the primary key is a CHAR or VARCHAR. It could be that anything but scan mode FULL calls this `a_plus_b_mul_c_minus_d` function that assumes a numeric primary key? If your case is a character primary key too, I suggest contacting Oracle Support referencing bug 19158337 - it seems it is suspended status at the moment, your input could help speed up the bug getting fixed.

Comment: Almost every table in my db contains varchar based keys ... So this explains everything. I'll check the bug number you've shared to add my own experiment of the issue to it. Thanks !